# palindrome number - compiler neither compiling code nor showing any error

Tags: c

can anyone help me this c program.i am trying to execute this palindrome check code but its not getting executed after i enter number.is there any error?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num,rev=0,r,temp;
    printf("enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    temp=num;
    while(num>0)
    {
        r=num%10;
        rev=(rev*10)+r;
        temp=temp/10;
    }
    if(num==rev)
    {
        printf("the number is palindrome %d: ",temp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is not a palindrome",temp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the block shows nothing, neither it stops executing.i tried it in code block and some online websites.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile so look for compiler errors.  In particular, various braces are missing.  Once you get past that, figure out what your loop should be - currently it uses `n` which is undeclared and doesn't change in the loop.

Comment: If you post code, please make sure that it at least compiles, and apply ordinary formatting to it. Keep an eye on how to write a [complete, minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Fixed it this time for you (missing braces, indentation only). Never post code as images, only textually .

Comment: The code in the image is different than the posted code.

Comment: this code now compiles and runs to completion. Whats the question? https://ideone.com/6LfheJ

Comment: Yes, its working .thank you everyone

Comment: "it's working" - how comes you do not end in an endless loop with `while(num > 0)` without modifying `num`? You should have `num /= 10` in the loop instead of modifying `temp`. Additionally, you use int as input variable, but do not deal with bad user input (negative numbers).

Comment: aha - my comment was based on passing 0 in as the input. Worked fine :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have an infinite loop here as `num` does not change within the loop, so the outcome of `num>0` never changes:

```
 while(num>0)
    {
        r=num%10;
        rev=(rev*10)+r;
        temp=temp/10;
    }
```

Comment: i have rewritten this code and its working perfectly.

Comment: Really glad to hear that! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int num,r,sum=0,temp;

printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d",&num);

temp=num;
while(num){
     r=num%10;
     num=num/10;
     sum=sum*10+r;
}
if(temp==sum)
     printf("%d is a palindrome",temp);
else
     printf("%d is not a palindrome",temp);

return 0;
}
```

i still don't get this issue but its working perfectly.
[image: rewritten code.]

[image: code working]